# How to use multiple tableviews by using Multiple custom class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have xib files there I used create multiple table with multiple custom xib cell, but I got the problem while load the multiple custom cell. i am getting error on code of cell rowat indexpath...i dont know how to do that with multiple tableview with multiple custom cell 
any one help me to solve this issues 
Thanks in Advance

```
func TablecellRegisternib() {

       self.Hight_table.register(UINib(nibName: "tableviewcellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.weight_table.register(UINib(nibName: "tableviewcellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
         self.Gender_table.register(UINib(nibName: "tableviewcellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
           self.Weekday_table.register(UINib(nibName: "tableviewcellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.Gym_tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "GymTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")

    self.Sports_tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "SpotsTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")

   self.AdditioanlSports_tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "AdditioanlSpotsTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell3")
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of items in the sample data structure.

        var count:Int?

        if tableView == self.weight_table {
            count = WightUnitArray.count
        }


        if tableView == self.Hight_table {
            count =  HightUnitArray.count

        }


        if tableView == self.Weekday_table {
            count =  WeekdayArray.count

        }

        if tableView == self.Gender_table {
            count = GenderArray.count
        }
        if tableView == self.Sports_tableview {
           count =  SportsArray.count

       }

 if tableView == self.AdditionalSports_tableview {
           count =  AdditionalSportsArray.count

       }

        return count!

    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        if tableView == self.weight_table {
              let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! tableviewcellTableViewCell

            cell.detail_lbl.text=WightUnitArray[indexPath.row]

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none;
            cell.detail_lbl.font = UIFont(name:"Roboto-Regular", size:13)
            cell.detail_lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true


            if (selectedIndex == indexPath as NSIndexPath?) {
                cell.radi_btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_btn_active.png"),for:UIControlState.normal)
            } else {
                cell.radi_btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_btn.png"),for:UIControlState.normal)
            }

        }

        if tableView == self.Hight_table {
              let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! tableviewcellTableViewCell

            cell.detail_lbl.text=HightUnitArray[indexPath.row]

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none;
            cell.detail_lbl.font = UIFont(name:"Roboto-Regular", size:13)
            cell.detail_lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true


            if (selectedIndex == indexPath as NSIndexPath?) {
                cell.radi_btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_btn_active.png"),for:UIControlState.normal)
            } else {
                cell.radi_btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_btn.png"),for:UIControlState.normal)
            }

        }




        if tableView == self.Weekday_table {
                 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! tableviewcellTableViewCell

            cell.detail_lbl.text=WeekdayArray[indexPath.row]

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none;
            cell.detail_lbl.font = UIFont(name:"Roboto-Regular", size:13)
            cell.detail_lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true


            if (selectedIndex == indexPath as NSIndexPath?) {
                cell.radi_btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_btn_active.png"),for:UIControlState.normal)
            } else {
                cell.radi_btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_btn.png"),for:UIControlState.normal)
            }

        }


        if tableView == self.Gender_table {
               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! tableviewcellTableViewCell

            cell.detail_lbl.text=GenderArray[indexPath.row]

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none;
            cell.detail_lbl.font = UIFont(name:"Roboto-Regular", size:13)
            cell.detail_lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true


            if (selectedIndex == indexPath as NSIndexPath?) {
                cell.radi_btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_btn_active.png"),for:UIControlState.normal)
            } else {
                cell.radi_btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_btn.png"),for:UIControlState.normal)
            }

        }


        if tableView == self.Gym_tableview {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as! GymTableCell
                var GymDict = GymtableArray[indexPath.row]
                cell.sportlbl!.text = GymDict["name"] as? String

                cell.sportlbl?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
                cell.sportlbl?.font = UIFont(name:"Roboto-Regular", size:13)
                return cell

            }

 if tableView == self.Sports_tableview {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell3") as! SportsTableCell
                var SportsDict = SportsArray[indexPath.row]
                cell.sportlbl1!.text = SportsDict["name"] as? String

                cell.sportlbl1?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
                cell.sportlbl1?.font = UIFont(name:"Roboto-Regular", size:13)
                return cell

            }



        return cell
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


          if tableView == self.weight_table {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
        let row = indexPath.row

        selectedIndex = indexPath as NSIndexPath?


        let weightstring = (WightUnitArray[row])
            if( weightstring != "Pound")
            {
            self.WeightUnitTabletxt.text = "kg"

            }
            else{
            self.WeightUnitTabletxt.text = "lbs"
            }

        self.Weight_View.isHidden = true
        tableView.reloadData()
            }

        if tableView == self.Hight_table {

            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
            let row = indexPath.row

            selectedIndex = indexPath as NSIndexPath?
            let Hightstr = (HightUnitArray[row])
            if( Hightstr != "Feet")
            {
                self.HeightUnitTabletxt.text = "m"

            }
            else{
                self.HeightUnitTabletxt.text = "ft"
            }

            self.Hight_view.isHidden = true
            tableView.reloadData()
        }



        if tableView == self.Weekday_table {

            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
            let row = indexPath.row

            selectedIndex = indexPath as NSIndexPath?
            self.FirstDayofWeek_txt.text = (WeekdayArray[row])
            self.FirstdayoftheWeek_view.isHidden = true
            tableView.reloadData()
        }


        if tableView == self.Gender_table {

            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
            let row = indexPath.row

            selectedIndex = indexPath as NSIndexPath?
            self.gender_txt.text = (GenderArray[row])
            self.Genderview.isHidden = true
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

Comment: What problem exactly do you have?

Comment: i cant load the data ...i am new for the swift developement.

Comment: how to do the multiple tableview with multiple custom cell

Comment: The flow of your code seems to be correctly setup, what is your problem as you said `i am getting error on code of cell rowat indexpath..` can you please mention the error you are getting ?

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
}

        return cell
    }

Comment: this line i got error like return cell the line i got error